# Can i using ClosedRange<T> in hibernate entity

Tags: hibernate, kotlin

Hibernate was throw below exception when using `ClosedRange<T>`

I know walk around is create own Range class with `@Entity` or `@Embeddable`,
but no another solution?

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: kotlin.ranges.IntRange, at table: Foo, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(myRange)]
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
class Foo (
    @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null,
    var myRange: IntRange = 0..0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
data Foo (
    @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Int? = null,
    var target: IntRange = target in 0..100  
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.